# Select values from XML field in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

Just looking at my XML field, my rows look like this:

```
<person><firstName>Jon</firstName><lastName>Johnson</lastName></person>
<person><firstName>Kathy</firstName><lastName>Carter</lastName></person>
<person><firstName>Bob</firstName><lastName>Burns</lastName></person>
```

Note that these are three rows in my table.

I'd like to return a SQL result as a table as in

```
Jon  | Johnson
Kathy| Carter
Bob  | Burns
```

What query will accomplish this?

Comment: Is there no way to just get ALL the elements in the xml? You have to specify one by one? That gets really tedious fast.

You can do "select * from table", seems like you should be able to do "select xml.* from xml" without having to specify every single element you want.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Given that the XML field is named 'xmlField'...

```
SELECT 
[xmlField].value('(/person//firstName/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FirstName,
[xmlField].value('(/person//lastName/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as LastName
FROM [myTable]
```

Comment: You must use .nodes() and cross apply if xmlField contains more than one <person> elements.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, returned me this error with your solution:
`The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.`; On the other hand @Remus Rusanu seems to do it :)

Comment: Bizarre.  This has been voted up 102 times, but this answer only returns data from the *first* XML record.   And it refers to some [myTable] table... where did that come from ?!

Comment: I have tried this so many times and never had it working.
My XML is `<BAM><Type>Electrical</Type><BaIds><a:int>7330</a:int></BaIds></BAM>`, my select is `select e.MessageData.value('(/BAM/Type)[1]', 'varchar(100)')`. I have also tried select `e.MessageData.value('(/BAM/Type/node())[1]', 'varchar(100)')`, and `'(//Type/node())[1]'`, `'(./Type)[1]'`, and every other combination I can think of.
All I ever get is `NULL`.

Comment: If the xml has given a namespace `xmlns="http://bayerbbs.com/AMUNI"` you have to map it to deafutl namespace `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://bayerbbs.com/AMUNI')
SELECT ...` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467387/ignore-xml-namespace-in-t-sql
`

Comment: @MikeGledhill it returns values from multiple XML records fine for me. Also the only name to the table the OP gives is "my table" :)

Comment: @MikeGledhill The original question says "these are three rows in my table" so [myTable] refers to whatever that table is called. If you are querying some single XML variable,then [1] will only give you one row. The syntax is not straight forward, but for a table [myTable] that has a column [xmlField] of type xml, this is one of the two correct answers, the other being Remus Rusanu's.

Answer (score 134):

Considering that XML data comes from a table 'table' and is stored in a column 'field': use the [XML methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx), extract values with [`xml.value()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx), project nodes with [`xml.nodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx), use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) to join:

```
SELECT 
    p.value('(./firstName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(8000)') AS firstName,
    p.value('(./lastName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(8000)') AS lastName
FROM table 
    CROSS APPLY field.nodes('/person') t(p)
```

You can ditch the `nodes()` and `cross apply` if each field contains exactly one element 'person'. If the XML is a variable you select `FROM @variable.nodes(...)` and you don't need the `cross apply`.

Comment: I wonder how efficient this method is and whether there's a better way. The CROSS APPLY combiend with XPath results seems like it might result in quite a resource hungry query.

Comment: @thelocster: this is no different from ordinary data access. Techniques for improving XML performance are well documented. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345118%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: keep in mind that if your XML has xmlns namespaces defined, you'll need to define those in the XQuery (XPath) expression above. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1302150/656010 for an example.

Comment: Slightly different to what I was needing, but this was a perfect solution to a problem I was having which was multiple rows with an XML column - I wanted to loop through rows and pull out the data fields from within the XML column and put them in an insert statement. So 5 rows, each for 3 columns of data in the XML field = 15 inserts, perfect.

Comment: As @Tom said the namespace is very important. Even if you do `SELECT TOP 1` without the correct namespace it'll take FOREVER!

Answer (score 19):

This post was helpful to solve my problem which has a little different XML format...  my XML contains a list of keys like the following example and I store the XML in the SourceKeys column in a table named DeleteBatch:

```
<k>1</k>
<k>2</k>
<k>3</k>
```

Create the table and populate it with some data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DeleteBatch (
    ExecutionKey INT PRIMARY KEY,
    SourceKeys XML)

INSERT INTO dbo.DeleteBatch ( ExecutionKey, SourceKeys )
SELECT 1, 
    (CAST('<k>1</k><k>2</k><k>3</k>' AS XML))

INSERT INTO dbo.DeleteBatch ( ExecutionKey, SourceKeys )
SELECT 2, 
    (CAST('<k>100</k><k>101</k>' AS XML))
```

Here's my SQL to select the keys from the XML:

```
SELECT ExecutionKey, p.value('.', 'int') AS [Key]
FROM dbo.DeleteBatch
    CROSS APPLY SourceKeys.nodes('/k') t(p)
```

Here's the query results...

```
ExecutionKey    Key
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   100
2   101
```

Answer (score 10):

This may answer your question:

```
select cast(xmlField as xml) xmlField into tmp from (
select '<person><firstName>Jon</firstName><lastName>Johnson</lastName></person>' xmlField
union select '<person><firstName>Kathy</firstName><lastName>Carter</lastName></person>'
union select '<person><firstName>Bob</firstName><lastName>Burns</lastName></person>'
) tb

SELECT
    xmlField.value('(person/firstName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FirstName
    ,xmlField.value('(person/lastName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as LastName
FROM tmp

drop table tmp
```

Answer (score 5):

Blimey.  This was a really useful thread to discover.

I still found some of these suggestions confusing.  Whenever I used `value` with `[1]` in the string, it would only retrieved the first value.  And some suggestions recommended using `cross apply` which (in my tests) just brought back far too much data.

So, here's my simple example of how you'd create an `xml` object, then read out its values into a table.

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(2000)

SET @str = ''
SET @str = @str + '<users>'
SET @str = @str + '  <user>'
SET @str = @str + '     <firstName>Mike</firstName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <lastName>Gledhill</lastName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <age>31</age>'
SET @str = @str + '  </user>'
SET @str = @str + '  <user>'
SET @str = @str + '     <firstName>Mark</firstName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <lastName>Stevens</lastName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <age>42</age>'
SET @str = @str + '  </user>'
SET @str = @str + '  <user>'
SET @str = @str + '     <firstName>Sarah</firstName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <lastName>Brown</lastName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <age>23</age>'
SET @str = @str + '  </user>'
SET @str = @str + '</users>'

DECLARE @xml xml
SELECT @xml = CAST(CAST(@str AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) 

--  Iterate through each of the "users\user" records in our XML
SELECT 
    x.Rec.query('./firstName').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'FirstName',
    x.Rec.query('./lastName').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'LastName',
    x.Rec.query('./age').value('.', 'int') AS 'Age'
FROM @xml.nodes('/users/user') as x(Rec)
```

And here's the output:

[image]

It's bizarre syntax, but with a decent example, it's easy enough to add to your own SQL Server functions.

Speaking of which, here's the *correct* answer to this question.

Assuming your have your xml data in an `@xml` variable of type `xml` (as demonstrated in my example above), here's how you would return the three rows of data from the xml quoted in the question:

```
SELECT 
    x.Rec.query('./firstName').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'FirstName',
    x.Rec.query('./lastName').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'LastName'
FROM @xml.nodes('/person') as x(Rec)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this is the correct answer. The OP is asking for querying a column from a table which is of type XML, and in that case you have to either use `[1]` , the index ordinal to force it to return 1 row, or you have to cross apply the column with `nodes()` to get a structure that can have xpath run against it. Your code doesn't translate to that scenario without a lot of modifications. You're using a variable, not a table column. You're also overusing `query()` function which returns xml. 
e.g. you could have just `x.Rec.value('(./firstName)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS FirstName`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
cast(xmlField as xml).value('(/person//firstName/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FirstName,
cast(xmlField as xml).value('(/person//lastName/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as LastName
FROM [myTable]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to wrap your XML in a root element - say  then the following is your solution:

```
DECLARE @PersonsXml XML = '<persons><person><firstName>Jon</firstName><lastName>Johnson</lastName></person>
<person><firstName>Kathy</firstName><lastName>Carter</lastName></person>
<person><firstName>Bob</firstName><lastName>Burns</lastName></person></persons>'

SELECT  b.value('(./firstName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') as FirstName, b.value('(./lastName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') as LastName
FROM @PersonsXml.nodes('/persons/person') AS a(b)
```

[image]

Comment: Best and simplest solution

Answer (score 3):

MSSQL uses regular XPath rules as follows:

- nodename     Selects all nodes with the name "nodename"
- /    Selects from the root node
- //   Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are
- .    Selects the current node
- ..   Selects the parent of the current node
- @    Selects attributes

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

/*
This example uses an XML variable with a schema
*/

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.xml_schema_collections 
           WHERE name = 'OrderingAfternoonTea')
BEGIN
    DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.OrderingAfternoonTea 
END
GO

CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.OrderingAfternoonTea AS
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     targetNamespace="http://Tfor2.com/schemas/actions/orderAfternoonTea"
     xmlns="http://Tfor2.com/schemas/actions/orderAfternoonTea"
     xmlns:TFor2="http://Tfor2.com/schemas/actions/orderAfternoonTea"
     elementFormDefault="qualified"
     version="0.10"
   > 
    <xsd:complexType name="AfternoonTeaOrderType">
       <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="potsOfTea" type="xsd:int"/>
         <xsd:element name="cakes" type="xsd:int"/>
         <xsd:element name="fruitedSconesWithCream" type="xsd:int"/>
         <xsd:element name="jams" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="schemaVersion" type="xsd:long" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="afternoonTeaOrder"
                 type="TFor2:AfternoonTeaOrderType"/>

  </xsd:schema>' ;
GO

DECLARE @potsOfTea int;
DECLARE @cakes int;
DECLARE @fruitedSconesWithCream int;
DECLARE @jams nvarchar(128);

DECLARE @RequestMsg NVARCHAR(2048);
DECLARE @RequestXml XML(dbo.OrderingAfternoonTea);

set @potsOfTea = 5;
set @cakes = 7;
set @fruitedSconesWithCream = 25;
set @jams = N'medlar jelly, quince and mulberry';

SELECT @RequestMsg = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<TFor2:afternoonTeaOrder schemaVersion="10"
    xmlns:TFor2="http://Tfor2.com/schemas/actions/orderAfternoonTea">
    <TFor2:potsOfTea>' + CAST(@potsOfTea as NVARCHAR(20)) 
        + '</TFor2:potsOfTea>
    <TFor2:cakes>' + CAST(@cakes as NVARCHAR(20)) + '</TFor2:cakes>
    <TFor2:fruitedSconesWithCream>' 
        + CAST(@fruitedSconesWithCream as NVARCHAR(20))
        + '</TFor2:fruitedSconesWithCream>
    <TFor2:jams>' + @jams + '</TFor2:jams>
</TFor2:afternoonTeaOrder>';

SELECT @RequestXml  = CAST(CAST(@RequestMsg AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) ;

with xmlnamespaces('http://Tfor2.com/schemas/actions/orderAfternoonTea'
                    as tea)
select
    cast( x.Rec.value('.[1]/@schemaVersion','nvarchar(20)') as bigint )
        as schemaVersion,
    cast( x.Rec.query('./tea:potsOfTea')
               .value('.','nvarchar(20)') as bigint ) as potsOfTea,
    cast( x.Rec.query('./tea:cakes')
               .value('.','nvarchar(20)') as bigint )  as cakes,
    cast( x.Rec.query('./tea:fruitedSconesWithCream')
               .value('.','nvarchar(20)') as bigint ) 
      as fruitedSconesWithCream,
    x.Rec.query('./tea:jams').value('.','nvarchar(50)')  as jams
from @RequestXml.nodes('/tea:afternoonTeaOrder')  as x(Rec);

select @RequestXml.query('/*')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
DECLARE @myDoc XML  
DECLARE @ProdID INT  
SET @myDoc = '<Root>  
<ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">  
<Features>  
  <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>  
  <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>  
</Features>  
</ProductDescription>  
</Root>'  
  
SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/Root/ProductDescription/@ProductID)[1]', 'int' )  
SELECT @ProdID
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **xml shredding** works good:
https://dzone.com/articles/dude-lets-xml-shred

XML:

```
DECLARE @x XML
SET @x = '
<Library>
  <Books>
    <Book Type="Paperback">
      <Author>Robert Jordan</Author>
      <Id>26</Id>
      <PublicationDate>01/15/1990</PublicationDate>
      <Series>
        <Name>The Wheel of Time</Name>
        <Number>1</Number>
      </Series>
      <Title Chapters="53">The Eye of the World</Title>
    </Book>
    <Book Type="Hardback">
      <Author>Robert Jordan</Author>
      <Id>87</Id>
      <PublicationDate>09/15/1992</PublicationDate>
      <Series>
        <Name>The Wheel of Time</Name>
        <Number>4</Number>
      </Series>
      <Title Chapters="58">The Shadow Rising</Title>
    </Book>
    <Book Type="eBook">
      <Author>Robert Jordan</Author>
      <Id>43</Id>
      <PublicationDate>05/15/1996</PublicationDate>
      <Series>
        <Name>The Wheel of Time</Name>
        <Number>7</Number>
      </Series>
      <Title Chapters="41">A Crown of Swords</Title>
    </Book>
  </Books>
  <Id>51</Id>
  <Name>We Have Books... Read Them or Else!</Name>
</Library>'
```

Query:

```
SELECT Books.Book.value('(./Id)[1]', 'INT') AS Id,
       Books.Book.value('(./Title)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Title,
       Books.Book.value('(./Author)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Author,
       Books.Book.value('(./PublicationDate)[1]', 'DATE') AS PublicationDate,
       Books.Book.value('(./Series/Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS SeriesName,
       Books.Book.value('(./Series/Number)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS SeriesNumber,
       Books.Book.value('@Type', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS BookType,
       Books.Book.value('(./Title/@Chapters)[1]', 'INT') AS Chapters
FROM @x.nodes('(/Library/Books/Book)') AS Books(Book)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgExP.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can write very easily, Please find the following details

```html
DECLARE @xmlData XML='
<person><firstName>Jon</firstName><lastName>Johnson</lastName></person>
<person><firstName>Kathy</firstName><lastName>Carter</lastName></person>
<person><firstName>Bob</firstName><lastName>Burns</lastName></person>'

SELECT 
Col.value('(firstName)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS [FirstName], 
Col.value('(lastName)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS [LastName]
FROM @xmlData.nodes('person') AS tbl(Col)
```

[Click to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBvWy.jpg)