# XML Query within SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I just starting to query XML within a SQL Server database.  I am having trouble with the most basic query.  Here is a simplified example.  How do I return description? The SELECT statement below is what I am using, but it returns nothing.

```
SELECT Incidents.IncidentXML.query
('data(/dsIncident/IncidentInformation/Description)') AS Description 
FROM Incidents
```

This is the snippet of the XML file that I am using:

```
<dsIncident xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsIncident.xsd">
  <IncidentInformation>
    <Description>This is the description.</Description>
    <Country>Singapore</Country>
  </IncidentInformation>
</dsIncident>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you're missing out on the XML namespace! :-)

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  Incidents.IncidentXML.query('declare namespace x="http://tempuri.org/dsIncident.xsd";
          (/x:dsIncident/x:IncidentInformation/x:Description)') AS Description 
FROM Incidents
```

The magic is the

```
declare namespace x="http://tempuri.org/dsIncident.xsd"
```

part here - it declares a namespace (with a prefix of your choice - can be anything - here 'x') for the period of the query on that XML data.

Hopefully, that'll return something! ;-)

Marc