# Convert Xml to Table SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I wonder how can i read a xml data and transform it to a table in TSQL?

For example:

```
<row>
    <IdInvernadero>8</IdInvernadero>
    <IdProducto>3</IdProducto>
    <IdCaracteristica1>8</IdCaracteristica1>
    <IdCaracteristica2>8</IdCaracteristica2>
    <Cantidad>25</Cantidad>
    <Folio>4568457</Folio>
</row>
<row>
    <IdInvernadero>3</IdInvernadero>
    <IdProducto>3</IdProducto>
    <IdCaracteristica1>1</IdCaracteristica1>
    <IdCaracteristica2>2</IdCaracteristica2>
    <Cantidad>72</Cantidad>
    <Folio>4568457</Folio>
</row>
```

To

```
8   3   8   8   25  4568457
3   3   1   2   72  4568457
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This is the answer, hope it helps someone :)

First there are two variations on how the xml can be written:

## 1

```
<row>
    <IdInvernadero>8</IdInvernadero>
    <IdProducto>3</IdProducto>
    <IdCaracteristica1>8</IdCaracteristica1>
    <IdCaracteristica2>8</IdCaracteristica2>
    <Cantidad>25</Cantidad>
    <Folio>4568457</Folio>
</row>
<row>
    <IdInvernadero>3</IdInvernadero>
    <IdProducto>3</IdProducto>
    <IdCaracteristica1>1</IdCaracteristica1>
    <IdCaracteristica2>2</IdCaracteristica2>
    <Cantidad>72</Cantidad>
    <Folio>4568457</Folio>
</row>
```

Answer:

```
SELECT  
       Tbl.Col.value('IdInvernadero[1]', 'smallint'),  
       Tbl.Col.value('IdProducto[1]', 'smallint'),  
       Tbl.Col.value('IdCaracteristica1[1]', 'smallint'),
       Tbl.Col.value('IdCaracteristica2[1]', 'smallint'),
       Tbl.Col.value('Cantidad[1]', 'int'),
       Tbl.Col.value('Folio[1]', 'varchar(7)')
FROM   @xml.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col)
```

## 2.

```
<row IdInvernadero="8" IdProducto="3" IdCaracteristica1="8" IdCaracteristica2="8" Cantidad ="25" Folio="4568457" />                         
<row IdInvernadero="3" IdProducto="3" IdCaracteristica1="1" IdCaracteristica2="2" Cantidad ="72" Folio="4568457" />
```

Answer:

```
SELECT  
       Tbl.Col.value('@IdInvernadero', 'smallint'),  
       Tbl.Col.value('@IdProducto', 'smallint'),  
       Tbl.Col.value('@IdCaracteristica1', 'smallint'),
       Tbl.Col.value('@IdCaracteristica2', 'smallint'),
       Tbl.Col.value('@Cantidad', 'int'),
       Tbl.Col.value('@Folio', 'varchar(7)')

FROM   @xml.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col)
```

Taken from:

1. http://kennyshu.blogspot.com/2007/12/convert-xml-file-to-table-in-sql-2005.html
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Including your source material is great. I also found that you first have to read an XML string from the DB into a variable before you can process it. There appears to be no way to `SELECT FROM` a subquery that returns XML.

Comment: Apparently I spoke too soon. This post covers how to select XML without a variable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18361423/271351. Basically you `CROSS APPLY` the table with the field in the table that has the XML and then pull the `NODES` from the `CROSS APPLY`ed field.

Answer (score 30):

The `sp_xml_preparedocument` stored procedure will parse the XML and the `OPENXML` rowset provider will show you a relational view of the XML data.

For details and *more examples* check the [OPENXML documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

As for your question,

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = '<rows><row>
    <IdInvernadero>8</IdInvernadero>
    <IdProducto>3</IdProducto>
    <IdCaracteristica1>8</IdCaracteristica1>
    <IdCaracteristica2>8</IdCaracteristica2>
    <Cantidad>25</Cantidad>
    <Folio>4568457</Folio>
</row>
<row>
    <IdInvernadero>3</IdInvernadero>
    <IdProducto>3</IdProducto>
    <IdCaracteristica1>1</IdCaracteristica1>
    <IdCaracteristica2>2</IdCaracteristica2>
    <Cantidad>72</Cantidad>
    <Folio>4568457</Folio>
</row></rows>'

DECLARE @handle INT  
DECLARE @PrepareXmlStatus INT  

EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @XML  

SELECT  *
FROM    OPENXML(@handle, '/rows/row', 2)  
    WITH (
    IdInvernadero INT,
    IdProducto INT,
    IdCaracteristica1 INT,
    IdCaracteristica2 INT,
    Cantidad INT,
    Folio INT
    )  


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

Comment: This works well. Even better is you can use an existing table to define the schema in the with.

Comment: Here's how you can [upload a file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540442/5432315), instead of using a string (which isn't a super likely use case).

Comment: Aren't you supposed to close the handle when done?