# Automatically format XML from an SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an SQL table that has a column with XML. Each XML cell has the same format/structure.

```
Date        Company     XML response
2015-10-22  Bloomberg   <RetrieveGetDataResponse….
2015-10-23  Bloomberg   <RetrieveGetDataResponse….
2015-10-24  Bloomberg   <RetrieveGetDataResponse….
2015-10-25  Bloomberg   <RetrieveGetDataResponse….
2015-10-26  Bloomberg   <RetrieveGetDataResponse….
```

I would like to extract the XML info from the XML response column and stack it into 1 formatted table in Excel or any other table format.

Thanks,

Comment: 1) Which RDBMS you use? 2) Sample data especially XML full well-formed  example 3) Desired output

Comment: 1) I use a Microsoft SQL server Management Studio - 2) The XML is too long for me to post. I will update my question with a smaller XML string for the example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Xml to Table SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989395/convert-xml-to-table-sql-server)