# split comma separated string into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a string like this:

```
'1,A;2,B;3,C'
```

Is there anyway that I can split comma separated values into columns then split to rows by `;` like below:

```
ID Text
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @s varchar(50) = '1,A;2,B;3,C'
--convert string to xml table (I used HTML tags for clarity)
declare @xml xml = cast('<tr><td>' + replace(replace(@s, ';', '</td></tr><tr><td>'), ',', '</td><td>') + '</td></tr>' as xml)
--query the xml to get SQL table
select tbl.col.value('td[1]', 'int') [ID],
       tbl.col.value('td[2]', 'varchar(10)') [Text]
from @xml.nodes('/tr') tbl(col)
```

For more information: [Convert Xml to Table SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989395/convert-xml-to-table-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = '1,A;2,B;3,C'  

SELECT SUBSTRING(value, 1, CHARINDEX(',',value)-1) AS ID
, SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX(',',value)+1, LEN(value)) AS TEXT 
FROM(
SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> ''
) A
```