# Select nvarchar(max) xml fromat values from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following XML:

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="approvalSet">
      <value>
        <Approval>
          <ApprovalItem application="SP" id="9659102e" name="reporting_queue" operation="Add" />
          <ApprovalItem application="SP" id="1013b3f5" name="reporting_queue" operation="Add" />
          <ApprovalItem application="SP" id="09648f81" name="reporting_queue" operation="Add" />
        </Approval>
      </value>
    </entry>
    <entry key="DisplayName" value=" mike " />
    <entry key="Name" value="1222" />
    <entry key="policy" />
    <entry key="work">
      <value>
        <WorkLevel>Normal</WorkLevel>
      </value>
    </entry>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

I want to run a select sql that one of the column(attributes) has xml format(attached here). the sql is like:

```
SELECT 
    w.created,
    W.[attributes],
    W.[completer]
FROM [item_archive] W 
WHERE W.type='Manual'
```

How can I get the result of the records value from attributes column which has XML format as a new columns (`application`, `id`, `name`, and `operation`) values separably. The XML columns type is `nvarchar((max),null)`.

Comment: Why are you storing XML as a `varchar` when you have a perfect datatype for the job: `xml`. You can't use XQUERY against a `varchar` either

Comment: [Here's a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361423/6167855) with cross apply if you know the attribute names, or [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3989477/6167855) if it was stored as XML

Comment: Also, post your XML data as what it is `text`, not an image please.

Comment: I did not created that table.

Comment: <Attributes> <Map><entry key="approvalSet"><value> <Approval>
          <ApprovalItem application="SP" id="9659102e" name="reporting_queue"  operation="Add" /><ApprovalItem application="SP" id="1013b3f5" name="reporting_queue"  operation="Add" /><ApprovalItem application="SP" id="09648f81" name="reporting_queue"  operation="Add" />
          </Approval></value></entry><entry key="DisplayName" value=" mike "/>
    <entry key="Name" value="1222"/><entry key="policy"/> <entry key="work">
      <value><WorkLevel>Normal</WorkLevel></value>
    </entry></Map></Attributes>

Comment: Please post the desired output as well.

Comment: the results columns would be : w.created, application, id, name,operation, w.[completer]

Comment: @user2433850 There's an "edit" button on your question. Please use that to add the information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
    drop table if exists #item_archive 
    create table #item_archive
    ( 
      created datetime,
      attributes varchar(max) null,
      completer varchar(20),
      type varchar(20)
    )

    declare @d varchar(max) = '
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="approvalSet">
      <value>
        <Approval>
          <ApprovalItem application="SP" id="9659102e" name="reporting_queue" operation="Add" />
          <ApprovalItem application="SP" id="1013b3f5" name="reporting_queue" operation="Add" />
          <ApprovalItem application="SP" id="09648f81" name="reporting_queue" operation="Add" />
        </Approval>
      </value>
    </entry>
    <entry key="DisplayName" value=" mike " />
    <entry key="Name" value="1222" />
    <entry key="policy" />
    <entry key="work">
      <value>
        <WorkLevel>Normal</WorkLevel>
      </value>
    </entry>
  </Map>
</Attributes>'

    insert into #item_archive(created,attributes,completer,type)
    values (getdate(),@d,'joe','Manual')

    go

    with W as 
    (
      select *, cast(attributes as xml) attributes_xml
      from #item_archive
    )
    select 
        w.created,
        w.completer,
        A.ApprovalItem.value('@application','varchar(20)') application,
        A.ApprovalItem.value('@id','varchar(20)') id,
        A.ApprovalItem.value('@name','varchar(50)') name,
        A.ApprovalItem.value('@operation','varchar(20)') operation
    from  W
    cross apply W.attributes_xml.nodes('/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="approvalSet"]/value/Approval/ApprovalItem') A(approvalItem)
    where W.type = 'Manual'
```

outputs

```
created                 completer            application          id                   name                                               operation
----------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------
2018-12-04 16:41:03.550 joe                  SP                   9659102e             reporting_queue                                    Add
2018-12-04 16:41:03.550 joe                  SP                   1013b3f5             reporting_queue                                    Add
2018-12-04 16:41:03.550 joe                  SP                   09648f81             reporting_queue                                    Add

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: As I mentioned to my question the column type is not XML type is nvarchar((max),null). Your query does not working, I'm getting this error :The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml

Comment: Still your edit code has .nodes which does not solve the error.

Comment: Can you explain? The sample code runs without error on my laptop.

Comment: In your edit code still has .nodes and when I run the sql getting the same error :The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.

Comment: It is invoked on a column of type xml.  Check that you copied and pasted correctly.