# Converting XML to SQL - Multiple elements in the same node problem with repeating element names

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I got a really simple XML file that I want to convert to a table.

XML structure:

```
<ROOT>
  <ID>ID-20</ID> (ONLY 1 ID per file, this will be the first column)
  <ProductList>    
      <ProductID>A-1235</ProductID>
      <Quantity>100</Quantity>
      <Price>300</Price>
      <ProductID>A-12356</ProductID>
      <Quantity>110</Quantity>
      <Price>310</Price>
      <ProductID>A-123567</ProductID>
      <Quantity>120</Quantity>
      <Price>320</Price>
      ...
  </ProductList> 
</ROOT>
```

The second column would be ProductID, the 3rd Quantity, the 4th Price.

I could make each ProductID appear in separate rows with the first column but I can't make the respective Quantity and Price show next to the ProductID.

My code so far:

```
  SELECT T.C.value('../../../ID[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AS ID,
           C.value('.', 'nvarchar(20)') AS ProductID,
           C2.value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AS Quantity--,COMMENTED PRICE OUT FOR NOW
           --C2.value('(../Price/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AS Price
  FROM @Xml.nodes('/ROOT/ProductList/ProductID') AS T(C)
             cross apply C.nodes('../Quantity') AS T2(C2)
```

The Cross Apply part causes every Quantity to appear next to every ProductID.
I can't figure out the correct way to align these columns.

I found some similar questions here but I just couldn't figure this out for my case as the XML structure is a bit different.

Could someone please help me with this?
I'd appreciate it very much :)

**Problem SOLVED!**
Many thanks to all who contributed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with @marc_s, the XML structure is very fragile.

In any case, here is a solution for the current scenario.

@Shnugo recently came up with this approach here: [How to extract value form XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818143/how-to-extract-value-form-xml/63820061#63820061)

All credit goes to him.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<ROOT>
    <ID>ID-20</ID>
    <ProductList>
        <ProductID>A-1235</ProductID>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <Price>300</Price>
        <ProductID>A-12356</ProductID>
        <Quantity>110</Quantity>
        <Price>310</Price>
        <ProductID>A-123567</ProductID>
        <Quantity>120</Quantity>
        <Price>320</Price>...</ProductList>
</ROOT>';

WITH tally(Nmbr) AS
(
    SELECT TOP(@xml.value('count(/ROOT/ProductList/ProductID)','INT'))
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT tally.Nmbr
      ,@xml.value('(/ROOT/ID/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(20)') AS ID
      ,@xml.value('(/ROOT/ProductList/ProductID[sql:column("tally.Nmbr")]/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(200)') AS ProductID
      ,@xml.value('(/ROOT/ProductList/Quantity[sql:column("tally.Nmbr")]/text())[1]','INT') AS Quantity 
      ,@xml.value('(/ROOT/ProductList/Price[sql:column("tally.Nmbr")]/text())[1]','INT') AS Price 
FROM tally;
```

**Output**

```
+------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+
| Nmbr |  ID   | ProductID | Quantity | Price |
+------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+
|    1 | ID-20 | A-1235    |      100 |   300 |
|    2 | ID-20 | A-12356   |      110 |   310 |
|    3 | ID-20 | A-123567  |      120 |   320 |
+------+-------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Ahhh, here's the triple ;-) +1 from my side

Comment: Yitzhak, no time for the moment, you might check this triple approach with a benchmark.

Comment: Thank you guys! This does the thing. I agree with the bad XML structure but it comes from a program I have no access to but I'll ask the creators so they might consider that to be a future upgrade. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your current XML structure is rather flawed...

What you **should have** (and that would easily allow to know what bits of information belong together) is an **element per product** - something like:

```
<ProductList>    
    <Product>
        <ID>A-1235</ID>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <Price>300</Price>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ID>A-12356</ID>
        <Quantity>110</Quantity>
        <Price>310</Price>
    </Product>
</ProductList>
```

because with the current structure you have, there's no **proper** and reliable way to know which `ProductId`, `Quantity` and `Price` belong together .... you won't be able to reliably get this information as you have it right now .....

With this structure, your query would be:

```
SELECT 
    C.value('(ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') AS ID,
    C.value('(Quantity)[1]', 'int') AS Quantity,
    C.value('(Price)[1]', 'decimal(16,2)') AS Price
FROM 
    @Xml.nodes('/ROOT/ProductList/Product') AS T(C)
```

Comment: Yes this is the structure I met a few times. I'll be sure to use this structure but this time the XML comes from a program I have no access to (I forgot to mention this). Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

..jff..

```
declare @x xml = N'
<ROOT>
  <ID>ID-20</ID> (ONLY 1 ID per file, this will be the first column)
  <ProductList>    
      <ProductID>A-1235</ProductID>
      <Quantity>100</Quantity>
      <Price>300</Price>
      <ProductID>A-12356</ProductID>
      <Quantity>110</Quantity>
      <Price>310</Price>
      <ProductID>A-123567</ProductID>
      <Quantity>120</Quantity>
      <Price>320</Price>
      ...........................
  </ProductList> 
</ROOT>';

select 
    [1],[2],[0], 
    cast([2] as int) as Quantity
from
(
select
    x.n.value('.', 'varchar(20)') as val,
    (row_number() over(order by x.n)-1) / 3 as grpid,
    row_number() over(order by x.n) % 3 as rowid
from @x.nodes('/ROOT/ProductList/*') as x(n)
) as src
pivot
(
max(val) for rowid in ([1],[2],[0])
) as pvt;
```