# Get table from XML on the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
declare @prueba xml 
set @prueba = '<obligaciones> 
            <obligacion> <Id>51</Id> </obligacion>
            <obligacion>  <Id>52</Id> </obligacion>
            <obligacion>  <Id>53</Id> </obligacion> 
           </obligaciones>'
```

I would like to get the following table from XML

```
select Id from @prueba....


51
52
53
```

Can sombody help with the query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899313/select-values-from-xml-field-in-sql-server-2008 already answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)

```
select T.N.value('(text())[1]', 'int') as Id
from @prueba.nodes('/obligaciones/obligacion/Id') as T(N)
```

**Update:**

With multiple values in the `obligaciones` node you can do like this:

```
declare @prueba xml set @prueba = '
<obligaciones>
  <obligacion>
    <id>51</id>
    <TipoCancelacionId>1</TipoCancelacionId>
  </obligacion>
  <obligacion>
    <id>52</id>
    <TipoCancelacionId>1</TipoCancelacionId>
  </obligacion>
  <obligacion>
    <id>53</id>
    <TipoCancelacionId>1</TipoCancelacionId>
  </obligacion>
</obligaciones>'

select T.N.value('(id/text())[1]', 'int') as Id,
       T.N.value('(TipoCancelacionId/text())[1]', 'int') as TipoCancelacionId
from @prueba.nodes('/obligaciones/obligacion') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
Id          TipoCancelacionId
----------- -----------------
51          1
52          1
53          1
```

Comment: Having 2 parameters in the XML, For example 

<!-- language-all: lang-xml-->

`declare @prueba xml 
set @prueba = '<obligaciones>
  <obligacion>
    <id>51</id>
    <TipoCancelacionId>1</TipoCancelacionId>
  </obligacion>
  <obligacion>
    <id>52</id>
    <TipoCancelacionId>1</TipoCancelacionId>
  </obligacion>
  <obligacion>
    <id>53</id>
    <TipoCancelacionId>1</TipoCancelacionId>
  </obligacion>
  </obligaciones>' 
` 



Any ideas?