# Translate xml data to SQL columns using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

I am new to XML using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a xml data  column named EventData the xml is structured like this...

```
<eventData>
  <Name> Mr Blog</Name>
  <Description> Hello World />
  <Date>10/06/2013</Date> 
</eventData>
```

What I require is each child element of eventData to be in a table stored like this

```
Key           Value
Name          Mr Blog
Description   Hello World
Date          10/06/2013
```

I read this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899313/select-values-from-xml-field-in-sql-server-2008/%22previous%20question%22) but does not solve my issue as my child elements are **dynamic** and they will not be the same each time.

Any ideas as to how I can structure my query to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by word Dynamic in this context - are the name of columns are not static or no of columns are not fixed and they very ?

Comment: The Column names and values can be different each time the query is run, the number of columns and the column names and their values will vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<eventData>
  <Name> Mr Blog</Name>
  <Description> Hello World </Description>
  <Date>10/06/2013</Date> 
</eventData>'

SELECT
    Name = XNodes.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'),
    VALUE = XNodes.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM @input.nodes('/eventData/*') AS XTbl(XNodes)
```

This gives me an output of:

[image]

and it's completely dynamic in that it will list of whatever subnodes your have under `<eventData>` and their value.

Comment: I thought I would add that as the data was from a data table, I used a CROSS APPLY to read the data from the XML column rather than declaring a variable.