# SELECT XML FROM TABLE IN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have XML stored in my table. This table has columns id  type int, and value type XML. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

XML looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <Weather>
 <Forecast>
 <Description>sky is clear</Description>
 <Date>6.9.2013 23:50:36</Date>
 <MinTemp>13</MinTemp>
 <MaxTemp>13</MaxTemp>
 <Pressure>995</Pressure>
 <Humidity>68</Humidity>
 </Forecast>
 </Weather>
```

This XML can have up to then Forecast parts. How can I with simple SELECT statement get for instance Humidity value?

I have been trying several thins I found here, but I keep getting NULL so that's the reason I'm asking this question.  Please help...

Comment: Check this similar question [Select values from XML field in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899313/select-values-from-xml-field-in-sql-server-2008). It might be helpful.

Comment: If you share some of the queries tried, someone might be able to identify a mistake, etc. that causes your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
select
  columnname
from
  MyTable
where
  columnname.value('(/Weather/Forecast)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like 'StringToSearchFor'
```

or as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899313/select-values-from-xml-field-in-sql-server-2008) like this:-

```
SELECT 
[xmlField].value('(/Weather//Forecast/Description/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as columname
FROM [myTable]
```

Comment: Thanks, really helped a lot! I was so close but couldn't find mistake. THANKS!

Comment: Can you please tell me what to do if I have XML that has 10 Forecast parts? I started using SQL few days ago so everything is new for me...

Comment: You have to specify nodes for all the 10 forecast parts!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one Forecast in your xml, use [nodes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) function:

```
select
    id, d.c.value('Humidity[1]', 'bigint') as Humidity
from test as t
    outer apply t.Data.nodes('Weather/Forecast') as d(c)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a613/2)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wish I could accept two answers, but can't. So Vote up!