# want to get the Email information from XML, But getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

```
CREATE TABLE XMLTABLE(id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,XML_DATA XML,DATE DATETIME);
go
INSERT INTO XMLTABLE(XML_DATA,DATE)
SELECT CONVERT(XML,BULKCOLUMN)AS DATA,getdate()
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\Demo.xml',SINGLE_BLOB)AS x
go
DECLARE @XML AS XML
DECLARE @OUPT AS INT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @XML= XML_DATA FROM XMLTABLE
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @OUPT OUTPUT,@XML,'<root xmlns:d="http://abc" xmlns:ns2="http://def" />'
SELECT EMAILR
FROM OPENXML(@OUPT,'d:ns2:FORM/ns2:Form1/ns2:Part/ns2:Part1/ns2:Ba')
WITH
(EMAILR [VARCHAR](100) 'ns2:EmailAddress')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @OUPT
go
```

---

i.e Demo.xml contains>>

```
<ns2:FORM xmlns="http://abc" xmlns:ns2="http://def">
 <ns2:Form1>
   <ns2:Part>
 <ns2:Part1>
 <ns2:Ba>
    <ns2:EmailA>Hello@YAHOO.COM</ns2:EmailA> ...
```

---

> Error:Msg 6603, Level 16, State 2, Line 6 XML parsing error: Expected
>   token 'eof' found ':'.
>
> d:ns2-->:<--FORM/ns2:Form1/ns2:Part/ns2:Part1/ns2:Ba

Comment: Please ask an actual question. For now we can see only poorly-formatter code, some error message and other parts difficult to identify/understand.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705045/select-xml-from-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: @SeekAndDestroy the linked question does not cover namespaces which adds quite an amount of troubles...

Answer (score 2):

The approach with `sp_xml_...` methods and `FROM OPENXML` is outdated!

You should better use the current XML methods `.nodes()`, `.value()`, `query()` and `.modify()`.

Your XML example is not complete, neither is is valid, had to change it a bit to make it working. You'll probably have to adapt the `XPath` (at least `Part1` is missing).

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<ns2:FORM xmlns="http://abc" xmlns:ns2="http://def">
  <ns2:Form1>
    <ns2:Part>
      <ns2:Ba>
        <ns2:EmailA>Hello@YAHOO.COM</ns2:EmailA>
      </ns2:Ba>
    </ns2:Part>
  </ns2:Form1>
</ns2:FORM> ';
```

This is the secure way with namespaces and full path

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://abc'
                  ,'http://def' AS ns2)
SELECT @xml.value('(/ns2:FORM/ns2:Form1/ns2:Part/ns2:Ba/ns2:EmailA)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

And this is the lazy approach

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//*:EmailA)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

You should - however - prefer the *full approach*. The more you give, the better and fast you get...