# Extract Columns names from XML file

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Just how we are able to pull out the column names from our table with this code:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'theNameofMyTable'
order by ordinal_position
```

Is there a similar function to pull out the names of a XML file's column names?

```
<Item>
    <Product>Food</Product>
    <Date>09/03/11</Date>
    <Shipped>10/01/11</Date> 
</Item>
```

I am wanting to write a code in sql that will pull out the column names in my xml files. I need to compare their schemas.

For this XML file, I'd want to see the column nodes: Product, Date, Shipped

Comment: Some db platforms have XML parsers built in.  What platform are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I'm really stumped on how to approach this - do you think I should look into parsing?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have an `XML` file and you want to use `SQL` to parse it?

Comment: The import wizard in SSMS can import XML, this would allow you to put your file into a table and then select the results out.  Is that along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: Sort of... I actually already have the xml in my sql. I have a large variety of very similar xmls that I am putting into a Table. I have been able to merge them however, I noticed the some of the xml have a slightly different schema than the others. Like for my example above, one xml might have an additional column <productID>. I'm trying to figure out a way to compare all of my xml columns to ensure I don't leave one out. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you would find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/899351/2589202) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml = '
<Item>
  <Product>Food</Product>
  <Date>09/03/11</Date>
  <Shipped>10/01/11</Shipped> 
</Item>'

select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)')
from @xml.nodes('/Item/*') as T(X)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18187)

Comment: Thanks so much Mikael! This solved my problem! You're a genius! Really appreciate your help! I have marked this as the correct answer and given you the up arrow! :)