# SQL Charindex and SUbstring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the `AccountNumber` on one of my columns with below sample value:

```
><AccountNumber>12345678</AccountNumber><Links>http://test@test123.com
```

the string length before and after the account number varies.

I have tried below code but the i cant figure out how to just extract the `AccountNumber`. Even the account number has different lengths.

```
Select  substring(XmlData,
                   charindex('><AccountNuber',XMLData),
                 50 )
   from Item with(nolock)
```

Comment: You may need to have a look to regexp parsing for SQL Server. But only if the is the only purpose of modifying this specific string. Don't user regexp to extensively parse XML or HTML. Use appropriate tool. Maybe SQL Server has XML parsing utility too? this could solve your issue too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server XML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445071/sql-server-xml-parsing)

Comment: checking the link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution should work if you only have a single `<AccountNumber>` tag for each record of the `XmlData` column.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(XmlData,
                 CHARINDEX('<AccountNumber>', XmlData) + 15,
                 CHARINDEX('</AccountNumber>', XmlData) -
                     (CHARINDEX('<AccountNumber>', XmlData) + 15));
```

If you want to extract multiple values, or if a given record could have multiple tags, then this approach won't work and you should consider using regular expressions, or better yet, an XML parser.

Comment: Hi, this wont work since the only constant here is the <AccountNumber> and </AccountNumber>, strings before and after them varies. also the account number between them varies.

Comment: @Ellyrose Yes, this will work, provided that `<AccountNumber>` and its closing tag are unique substrings.  Did you even bother trying my code?

Comment: yes i've tried thank you :)...i wonder why its not working..yes the tags for accountnymber is unique

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: this one of the result of the query..55555.7778881123</AccountNumber><Link /></Scanned:Exception>]]>  you see the end part is included...

Comment: Do you have more than one `<AccountNumber>` tag present?

Comment: @Ellyrose I have updated my answer and it should work now, there was a bug in there.

Comment: oh my... why i didn't think of that? :)

Comment: When I wrote the query, I assumed an offset of zero for the opening tag, this is why you got extra garbage at the end.  The new `CHARINDEX()` term offsets the capture so you get only the account number.

Comment: its now returning what i need.. thanks so much Tim! :)