# Can I store a list of objects to SQLite instead on breaking up the list and adding the objects individually?

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin, sqlite

I am storing a list of objects of a class to a SQLite table. The class has 30 strings and I have roughly 6000 objects of the class in my List. It's only 6MB. Breaking up this list and storing that takes almost a minute. But can I store the entire list as one? Here is my code so far:

```
    List<TheClass> ListOfObjects;

    public static void AddAllObjects() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfObjects.Count; i++) {
            AddObject(ListOfObjects[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void AddObject(Object obj) {
        database.SaveItem(obj);
    }

    public void SaveItem<T>(T item) {
        connection.Insert(item);
    }
```

Comment: You want to store the list as one row? Or do you want to store each object in the list as one row? What I mean is, are you looking to just serialize your list into a blob, or are you looking for something like bulk insert for sqlite?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen My current method seems incredibly inefficient mainly because of the amount of inserts. I would like to reduce that number some how. Perhaps a blob

Comment: It is possible with storing a xml into the database. But you need to serialize the data.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Serialising takes a lot of time too. I'm looking for a way to just store the List as it is. Like a blob

Comment: @james serialization is still required when storing it as a blob. The advantage of xml is, that sql can parse and select from it server side. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899313/select-values-from-xml-field-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @james If you do not like the option of serialization, then you also can use asynchronism

Comment: Storing it as a serialised JSON object with Newtonsoft.NET in a single string, has decreased writing to 12 seconds. But Reading has increased from 3 seconds to 7 seconds...

Comment: @james Regarding the original code, are you performing 6000 inserts within ***one*** transaction?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object `SQLiteConnection` of sqlite-net has the method `InsertAll`.

```
List<Object> models = new List<Object>();
// ...
// LocalConnection conn = ...;
SQLiteConnection db = conn.GetSQLiteConnection();
db.InsertAll(models,true); // the true means "run in transaction"
```

https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net/SQLiteConnection.cs

By the way it's implemented as a foreach inside a transaction, so I guess it's the only way, at least using sqlite-net.

Comment: Incredible, this has reduced it to 1126ms READ and 435ms WRITE.