# Display and parse data from column with XML in SSRS

Tags: xml, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am attempting to display data from a column in SQL that has XML in it. An example is below:

```
<ArrayOfTarget xmlns:i="http://www.example.org/example2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.example.org/2004/07/example.example.example.example.example">
  <Target>
    <AgencyId>b0ab0a3a-1299-cb19-d6c6-08d6f8dfab0f</AgencyId>
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id>337a22d8-e1d9-cdf2-240f-08d8622b44ac</Id>
    <Name>Case Number example</Name>
    <Type>Case Management</Type>
  </Target>
```

Is there a way to display in SSRS for example the data in "Name" in the XML?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899313/select-values-from-xml-field-in-sql-server-2008/18361423#18361423

Comment: I should clarify then. Without doing any work in SQL, can you directly display and parse data from a column with XML in report builder?